# Azure Deploy Code To Service Using ARM Template From VSTS Git Code

Tags: git, azure, arm, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have created an ARM template and am using it to:

- Create a resource group.
- Create and Application Service.
- Deploy code from GitHub (repoUrl) to said Application Service.

All works wonderfully when I place my project inside GitHub but we are using VSTS Git to hold our code. 
I know I can create a VSTS jobs that will do this for me and this is the track we will get to again however we need to be able to run these ARM templates from our developer machines, running direct from our Visual Studios or Powershell ISE's.

Almost everything works until it tries to add my C# project from VSTS Git to the service I get the following bland error report:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:08:30 - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols 'webapp1nameuniques83476y4589479/web' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."
  }
}'At C:\Users\[removed my directory]\Deploy-AzureResources.ps1:119 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:08:30 - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.At 
C:\Users\[removed my directory]\Deploy-AzureResources.ps1:119 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:08:30 - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.At 
C:\Users\[removed my directory]\Deploy-AzureResources.ps1:119 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

The template I am using is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "webapp1name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "webapp1nameuniques83476y4589479",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the web app that you wish to create."
      }
    },
    "webapp1hostingplan": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "hostingplantestname",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the App Service plan to use for hosting the web app."
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "S1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
      }
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "0",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The instance size of the hosting plan (small, medium, or large)."
      }
    },
    "repoURL": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The URL for the GitHub repository that contains the project to deploy."
      }
    },
    "branch": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "master",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to use."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('webapp1hostingplan')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('workerSize')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('webapp1hostingplan')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('webapp1name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('webapp1hostingplan'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[parameters('webapp1hostingplan')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "sourcecontrols",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webapp1name'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
            "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It ends with all resources created but the application service has no code project deployed to it.

any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you check your git? Your template works me fine. I test it with this simple [source](https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ToDoApp.git). I think it is not a template issue.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it is an authorisation issue then - darn these terrible error messages

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I can deploy the code from Github repo but there is no my project dll. I see only dependency dll in my App Service. I used this public repo https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ToDoApp. How I can specify my project sln path in ARM Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to Git repo hosted on VSTS is not public, they are private Git repo.

The workaround around is adding the credentials in the repo url.
[image]

Comment: Ok, I will test it.

Comment: @Phish I added a screenshot in my answer. Remember to use personal access token or alternative credential.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm? Create an alteranative credential (underneath the clone button in VSTS), and simply add the 'uname@pword' between host and visual studio reference in the clone URL?

Comment: @Phish The format is "https://username:password@xxx.visualstudio.com/_git/reponame".

Comment: Sorry it took so long - a username with an '@' will cause an internal server error with no useful feedback so had to use an alias.