# Azure - deploy web app connected to VSTS results in error: There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I am deploying azure web app (app services) through visual studio using arm template. At first there was a problem with connecting to VSTS source control. I didn't realize that VSTS git is private, so I had to create alias credentials in VSTS and use those credentials in arm template. Got solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034637/azure-deploy-web-app-from-visual-studio-using-arm-template-connected-to-vsts).

After this, web app was successfully deployed and connected to VSTS. But when I tried to repeat this I get an error:

> There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO.

Before deploying, I first delete all resources from previous deployment. So in general, I am just trying to repeat same deployment as the first time, but for some reason it is not working!

Template looks like this:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[parameters('site_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "enabled": true,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('site_name'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "virtualIP": null,
            "thumbprint": null,
            "toUpdate": null,
            "hostType": "Standard"
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('site_name'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "virtualIP": null,
            "thumbprint": null,
            "toUpdate": null,
            "hostType": "Repository"
          }
        ],
        "serverFarmId": "[parameters('site_serverFarmId')]",
        "reserved": false,
        "siteConfig": {
          "connectionStrings": [
            {
              "connectionString": "[parameters('connection_string_value')]",
              "name": "ServerConnectionString"
            }
          ]
        },
        "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
        "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
        "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
        "clientCertEnabled": false,
        "hostNamesDisabled": false,
        "containerSize": 0,
        "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
        "cloningInfo": null
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "sourcecontrols",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('site_name'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "repoUrl": "https://xxxx@xxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/xxxx",
            "branch": "master",
            "isManualIntegration": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "dependsOn": []
    }
```

Complete error:

```
{
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO"
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "01020",
        "MessageTemplate": "There was a conflict. {0}",
        "Parameters": [
          "Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
```

Does anybody know what this error means, and what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Did you delete the resource group? What's the result if change app service name?

Comment: My requirenment is to deploy two web apps and one data base. First app is comunicating with second and second web app is comunicating with data base. So, I first create resource group, then service plan, then deploy first web app connected to one VSTO source controll (url1), and after this I deploy second web app, also connected to VSTS (url2) source controll (using same service plan from as first web app). But deployment of this second web app constantly gives error from title! I tried creating separate service plans for each web app, but with no luck!

Comment: Do you mean deploy two apps to separate azure web apps? (two azure webs) or you are deploying two apps to an azure web app?

Comment: Yes, two separate web apps.

Comment: Have these web apps already been configured with Deployment Options?

Comment: Configuration for 'deployment options' are in arm template for each web app (sourcecontrols node). I am not configuring it manualy after deployment. After deployment from visual studio web app is connected to VSTO git (fetch performs ok) and usaly everything works, but sometimes I get error 'There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: VSO.' This can happen even for new web app (new web app name but same VSTO url).

Comment: I've just created new resource group, new service plan and new web app. I deployed just one web app this time, and still got same error! Unbelivable, now I can't get one web app to run corectlly.

Comment: What's the result if you deploy it to azure manually (e.g. via PowerShell)?